# Preventing brew cleanup from deleting specific old version of software

Tags: version-control, terminal, ansible, homebrew

I am a massive fan of Homebrew and have taken to using it to manage all my applications. One very useful feature is `brew switch` which enables switching between different versions of Ansible. Something which I require to compile some of my websites running older software.

However, I have noticed that whenever I wish to run `brew cleanup`, it deletes all old versions even version 2.3.2.0 of Ansible which I still require alongside the most current version.

After sifting through numerous forums and sites I have been unable to find a solution which allows me to keep this old version of Ansible and the most current when using the `brew cleanup` command other than deleting everything manually.

Does anyone have a workaround or solution, I thought `brew pin` may be a possibility, but this seems to only work with the version currently linked.

Comment: This is a valid question. Homebrew installs and updates multitple versions of a software. For example foo 2.0, foo 3.0, foo 4.0. Sometimes we want foo 4.0 and later, but to always keep foo 2.0 too. Reviewers are probably not familiar with Homebrew/Linuxbrew. Please migrate to apple.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a clean built-in way with `brew cleanup` to do this, but a workaround: since `brew cleanup` optionally takes a list of formulae to clean up, we can make such a list that contains everything but Ansible.

This is how I can get that list:

```
brew list | grep -v ansible
```

And this is how I can call `cleanup` to ignore Ansible:

```
brew cleanup $(brew list | grep -v ansible)
```

Maybe I want that as an alias somewhere, like `bca` for "**b**rew **c**leanup (but not) **a**nsible":

```
alias bca='brew cleanup $(brew list | grep -v ansible)'
```

and add that line to my `~/.bashrc`.